# How to see related objects when a model tried to be deleted in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

in a large database lets say I have Article_A and Article_A has some comments. Comment_1,Comment_2 and Comment_3. When I tried to delete Article_A I want to show a message to the user says that "Article_A has Comment_1, Comment_2 and Comment_3 and you shouldn't delete them". Moreover I want to show all related objects to Article_A(not only Comments). So should I be aware of all related objects to the Article_A query them?

Comment: Check this function from the django repo on GitHub. The thing you want is already implemented in Django's admin interface. https://github.com/django/django/blob/f8ef5f2c86683bef3b200fd864efc14f1fbbc23b/django/contrib/admin/utils.py#L103

Comment: Thanks I think this does what I want but it looks complicated to me. I need to understand how it does first

Answer (score -1):

Sorry i don't understand  you but you need in models.py:

if you want when youdelete one other delete on_delete=models.CASCADE

```
class Article(models.Model):
    Comment= models.OneToOneField(Comment, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

else

```
class Article(models.Model):
    Comment= models.OneToOneField(Comment,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Comment: Think in this way, in case of `on_delete=models.CASCADE`, I want to show related objects which are going to be deleted in database.